# AP Chemistry Practice exam

Tags: intermolecular-forces, lewis-structure

It's starts off the question with "Propanoic Acid, $\ce{C2H5COOH}$, is an organic acid that is a liquid at room temperature. An incomplete Lewis diagram for the propanoic acid molecule is provided in the box below. Complete the diagram, showing how the remaining atoms in the molecule are arranged around the carbon atom marked with an asterisk (*). Your structure should minimalize formal charge and include any lone pairs of electrons."[image]
I don't really know the best way to do A. For B I said $\text{sp}^2$ hybridization. For Ci, I said intermolecular forces and dipole dipole forces. For Cii, I said dipole dipole forces. Double check me please.

Comment: Oxygen forms two bonds. Where will it be placed? *Think carefully*.

Comment: Didn't it go with carbon? The asterisk one.

Comment: Would oxygen go into the right side of the carbon with the asterisk, then another oxygen right next to it?

Answer (score 1):

For part a, I assume that the question is asking you to complete the structure of the propanoic acid. Carboxylic acids always have a $\ce{-COOH}$ functional group as follows:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Carboxylic-acid.svg/1200px-Carboxylic-acid.svg.png[image]

As you can see, the R in propanoic acid is the ethyl ($\ce{CH3CH2}$) group.

For part b, the carbon is indeed sp2 hybridised as the carbon in question has 3 bond pairs.

For part c(i), the types of intermolecular forces present will be weak London Dispersion Forces, Hydrogen Bonding (due to $\ce{-OH}$) and Dipole-Dipole Forces.

As for part c(ii), both butanoic acid and propanoic acid contain the same functional groups, except that butanoic acid contains an extra $\ce{CH3}$. Hence, the same types of intermolecular forces will be present. However, the strength of London Dispersion Forces in butanoic acid will be stronger than that in propanoic acid since butanoic acid has a larger and hence more polarizable electron cloud. As a result, butanoic acid has a higher boiling point than propanoic acid.